# Prob. 22, Chap. 2, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: $m^{**}(A) = m^*(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, outer-measure

Here is Prob. 22, Chap. 2, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden & P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> For any set $A$, define $m^{**}(A) \in [0, \infty]$ by
> $$
> m^{**}(A) = \inf \left\{ m^*(O) \, | \, O \supseteq A, O \mbox{ open } \right\}.
> $$
> How is this set function $m^{**}$ related to outer measure $m^*$?

My Attempt:

> If O is any set (and in particular any open set) containing $A$, then by the monotonicity of the outer measure, we have $m^*(O) \geq m^*(A)$, that is, $m^*(A) \leq m^*(O)$, and thus $m^*(A)$ is a *lower bound* for the set $$ \left\{ m^*(O) \, | \, O \supseteq A, O \mbox{ open } \right\},  $$
> and since $m^{**}(A)$ is the *infimum* of this same set, we have the inequality
> $$
> m^*(A) \leq m^{**}(A). \tag{1} 
> $$

> Next, we show that
> $$
> m^{**}(A) \leq m^*(A) 
> $$
> also holds.

> If $m^*(A) = \infty$, then we trivially have
> $$
> m^{**}(A) \leq m^*(A).
> $$
> Therefore we assume that $m^*(A) < \infty$.

> Let $\epsilon$ be any real number such that $\epsilon > 0$. As $m^{*}(A)$ is the *infimum* of the set of all the sums $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_k \right)$, where $\left\{ I_k \right\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is any countable collection of non-empty bounded open intervals for which $A \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty I_k$, so for our particular $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a countable collection $\left\{ I_{\epsilon, k} \right\}_{k =1}^\infty$ of non-empty bounded open intervals such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{\epsilon, k}$ for which we have the inequalities
> $$
> m^*(A) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{\epsilon, k} \right) < m^*(A) + \epsilon. \tag{2} 
> $$

> Let us put $O_\epsilon := \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty I_{\epsilon, k}$. This set $O_\epsilon$ is an open set containing $A$, and we have
> $$
> m^*\left(O_\epsilon \right) = m^* \left( \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty I_{\epsilon, k} \right) \leq \sum_{k = 1}^\infty m^* \left( I_{\epsilon, k} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty l \left( I_{\epsilon, k} \right),
> $$
> which together with (2) yields
> $$
> m^* \left(O_\epsilon \right) < m^*(A) + \epsilon. 
> $$
> But as $O_\epsilon$ is an open set containing $A$, we also have $m^{**}(A) \leq m^*\left( O_\epsilon \right)$. Refer to the definition of $m^{**}(A)$ in the statement of this problem above. We therefore obtain
> $$
> m^{**}(A) \leq m^* \left( O_\epsilon \right) < m^*(A) + \epsilon,
> $$
> which implies
> $$
> m^{**}(A) < m^*(A) + \epsilon. \tag{3} 
> $$

> Since (3) holds for every real number $\epsilon > 0$, we can conclude that
> $$
> m^{**}(A) \leq m^*(A),
> $$
> which together with (1) above yields
> $$
> m^{**}(A) = m^*(A).
> $$

Is my finding correct? If so, is my derivation of this identity correct and clear enough too? Or, are there any lacunas?

Comment: I'd say to proof is fine. No lucunae that I see.